# Exchange Rate scenario. Which is the better option?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

You are travelling overseas.  If you use your ATM or Credit Card, you will be assessed a 3% surcharge on all transactions.

So, you decide to withdraw Euros at your local bank branch to see if you can avoid the 3% fee.   On a day where the EUR/USD exchange rate is 1.095, the bank will give you 1.165 rate.  (You pay $1.165 dollars for 1 Euro)

What is the effective surcharge rate you are paying by withdrawing currency at your local branch?  (Recall, the market rate on this given day is 1.095 and they are charging you 1.165)

Are you better off withdrawing cash before the trip, or incurring the 3% ATM fee once overseas?

If rate is 1.095, then 1 USD ~ .91 Euro.   (What you should get)
If rate is 1.165, then 1 USD ~ .86 Euro.  (what you actually get at branch)
That's a difference of .05, which ~ 5% of .91
So, you are getting "charged" almost 5% to exchange at the local branch.

Comment: Using your credit card (or ATM card) abroad there still has to be an exchange rate (as you will ultimately be billed in USD).  Do you know how the bank (or credit card company) sets that rate?

Comment: Let's say they just use fair market rate for transactions.

Comment: Well...ok.  Say midmarket is $1.09$, and, just to fix things, say you spend exactly 100 euro while abroad.  Then mid market would cost you \$109. Doing it with withdrawal costs you \$117 (a 7.34% "surcharge") and doing it with your ATM costs you $1.03*109 = \$112.7$.  Withdrawals are more than twice as costly.  But I don't believe your ATM card or credit card charge you midmarket.

Comment: Note:  you changed your numbers while I was typing, so my numerical values are no longer correct, but the steps still go through.

Comment: ATM and credit cards differ widely. My experience has been that many use the fair rate of exchange plus 2% or 3%. If you use a card issued through a US bank owned by a corporation in the eruozone maybe 0%. Often the largest factor to consider is fluctuations in the rate while traveling. Right now the euro is falling relative to the dollar and it would be foolish to buy euros in advance. Also, there is the risk of carrying a large amount of cash; more of an issue in some countries than others. (If this is purely a math exercise, it seems some info on the card charges is lacking.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local bank exchange was a bad deal.   I ended up using the ATM.   I used my debit card that did not incur intl' ATM fees.